# Looking For A Specific Isekai Manga

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for an Isekai manga that I read sometime ago. A few events that I remember from the manga is that the MC finds some pretty OP equipment after waking up in something akin to a barn, and because the equipment was so OP, he decided to not use it unless he really needed to. After that, I recall the MC getting caught up in a fight with bandits to protect the village where the barn was at, and from the battle, he gets some sort of bandit's bandana, which supposedly was an extremely expensive item amongst bandits. If I remember correctly, later in the manga, the MC infiltrates a bandit's hideout and kills the bandits for a reason that I don't remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Isekai Meikyuu de Harem o](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=141448)* or *A Harem in the Fantasy World Dungeon*

[image: Front cover of Isekai Meikyuu de Harem o]

> A man was about to commit suicide and decides to search for a way to die in the internet, but then he found an odd site that asked a lot of questions and had a point based system that allows you to create skills and abilities for a character. He took interest in it and when he finished setting his character he was asked "You will now be transported to a world with the settings you choose, coming back is not possible, do you still accept?" Then without thinking much of it he pressed YES and found himself in another world with the skills and abilities he chose to have.

He does use Appraisal to find two "bonus items" in the barn
[image: Finding the overpowered items in the barn]

And Appraisal also lets him notice that one of the villagers tried to substitute a regular Bandana for the Bandit Bandana he spotted on the leader during battle
[image: Bandit Bandana]

Found with a search for `isekai "bandit's bandana"`, which brought up some chapters of the webnovel the manga is based off of.